# xstream not including some fields even though they have getter/setters

Tags: java, xstream

I expected XStream to include "all fields" of a particular class but one of them isn't showing up even though it's not null.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was marked as "transient" at its declaration (`private transient XXX`) which XStream respected and didn't include it.  Even though the getter/setters were all public, that wasn't enough.